# Authorize attribute and InitializeSimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and this question might be a novice question. I have seen examples about `Authorize` attribute on the web. In these examples the authors controller code looks like this

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
Public class someController: Controller {...}
```

But if you check the AccountController you will find that

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
Public class AccountController: Controller {...}
```

So my question is why does the author not simply use `[Authorize]` without initializing Simple membership in the `someController` since it will be initialized any way if it reaches Account Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using InitializeSimpleMembership attribute it means that you may not using membership in your application every where, so if you are not using membership you may don't want to waste resources for it, so the attribute initialize simple membership for application in run time, if you are sure that the application will use simple membership you can just add this line of code to application start in global.asax `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);` and then get ride of InitializeSimpleMembership attribute every where, maybe author thinks that the membership don't have too many use cases, so decided to put the attribute in place, and maybe application use SomeController before calling any action of AccountController